# Why no programming in English? What is the difference between natural languages and programming languages?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, nlp

What is the key difference between natural languages (such as English and French) and programming languages like C++ and Perl?

I am familiar with the ambiguity problem, but can't it be solved using an interactive compiler or using a subset of the natural language using a strict grammar but all the time still retaining the essence of the language?

Another issue is context. But lawyers have ways to solve this issue. (This question is not about reducing the programming complexity, it's simply about concise reasons and roadblock in using natural languages for instructing computer.)

Is there any other significant problem besides these two? Or do these two have greater consequences than I mentioned above? Is the interactive solution and lawyers language technically not feasible for programming?

Comment: I don't know much about NLP. if this question can be formatted better, please submit edits to make it more concise. I will try to clarify if there's a doubt.

Comment: yes i have seen COBOL and while `ADD X TO Y` seems very close to english. 
`IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
      PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
      PROCEDURE DIVISION.
          DISPLAY 'Hello, world'.
          STOP RUN.`

doesnt look much english to me.

Comment: on the same line. i can also add http://inform7.com/ but this again isnt a programming language which i can use for wrting cron jobs or database queries.

Comment: Programming language terms (keywords, function names, API calls, etc) also *mean what they mean* in terms of their implementation i.e. the computation they perform.  The English words are used as a mnemonic (or not i.e. many Common Lisp functions) but the English words are *not* the meaning of the code.  Therefore, having the whole code read as closely approximating prose actually detracts from comprehension rather than aiding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three principal reasons.

First, as Gabe says - people have figured out through trial and error that programming in things that are close to English sentences only forces programmers to type more useless cruft. (And yes, COBOL was explicitly designed to read more "naturally".)

To a programmer,

```
windows++
```

is more readable than

```
You should now increment the number of windows by one.
```

For example, Tetris is a rather easy game to code. I would be terribly surprised if you managed to make an English explanation that is detailed enough for a computer (remember, computers are dumb, so you have to spell it all out) in less pages than a short novel.

The second reason is that the range of things a computer knows how to do is rather small, so the number of language constructs that are needed for that is also limited. In contrast, natural languages need to be able to express the entirety of human experience, which does require many language constructs to pull off. For example, "According to his wife, John would have caught the fish yesterday if it hadn't rained" is not expressible in C - and does not need to be.

And third is, indeed, ambiguity, as you yourself note. There are a lot of places where a software error is simply not permissible. People do enough bugs in unambiguous languages; allowing ambiguity would be a disaster waiting to happen. And on the same subject, we are still unable to parse human language sufficiently well - state of the art parsers still have unacceptably high error rates.

Comment: In a sufficiently high-level English interpreter, you could say "Create a window" and the expression "the number of windows" would automatically increase. (The interpreter could either keep a list of instances for each type/class or keep a master list that it can query by type.)

Answer (score 6):

This is an extremely interesting question and in short, yes, there are some very good reasons why we don't use English to write programs.

It's been said before that the greatest gift that computer science has given us is not the ability to talk to computers but now that formal languages exist for describing algorithms we now have even better tools for communicating these ideas to other people. Even if a computer is not involved. Indeed the best software engineers see their jobs primarily as writing software that is readable to other people so as to make maintenance and addition of new features as easy as possible. This is not possible in a language as big and as free form as any natural, spoken language.

### Ambiguity

One reason is that of ambiguity. Have you ever looked a menu in a restaurant and seen that with your burger you can get "Coleslaw and fries or salad"? What does this mean? Can I get both coleslaw and fries or the other option is a salad alone? Or do I always get coleslaw and I have to chose between the fries or a salad? English is full of these things.

I used to teach a class on this and an example I liked to use to explain ambiguity was as follows. I asked the students to write a one paragraph story ending with the sentence "Tom asked Chris if he could help him". About half the time the stories written indicated that the student interpreted the sentence as Tom asking for assistance from Chris. The other half of the time people thought Tom was offering to lend Chris a hand.

If you think about it, there are a lot of people who do write programs in English. They're called product managers and the compiler they use is software engineers. The problem here is that a software engineer has to inject a lot of his own understanding of the problem to understand what the description really means. And trust me, there is a *lot* of back and forth. Even on very simple business requirements I must clarify ambiguities.

### Context

I would not agree that lawyers have ways to solve the context problem. We continually have ongoing arguments in courts among, in some cases, some of the most educated people in the country, about the meanings of various laws. Sometimes this involves arguing about the context in which the laws were written long ago. Sometimes in involves applying it to a new, previously non-existent context like the Internet. The fact that we have thousands of lawyers working on disambiguating these issues is proof that it cannot be handled by a simple computer program like a compiler. It's just too hard of a problem.

### Conciseness

Another issue is just the ability to be concise. Mathematics long ago invented notations for many different concepts in the maths because it's just easier to read if there's a special syntax that is concise and has a well defined meaning. A mathematician knows what it means when I say "f(x) = 3x+1". It means the same thing as "There is a function called f and it has one argument. The value of applying f to a number is the number that is one more than three times the number given." But the former is a lot easier to read once you've learned the syntax. The same is true for programming languages. Programming languages are specialized to describe computations.

### Implementation

Creators of programming languages deliberately create very small languages. These are, in fact, subsets of English also with some extra syntax. The idea of understanding all of English in all of its free form ways and, worse yet, increasing vocabulary is a job for Natural Language Processing (NPL). A very hard job. If you want to be able to assign unambiguous meaning to a program and have the program's behavior never change, you need a well defined syntax and semantics.

The take-away point here is that English is a very big, very flexible language with no formal specification. Programming languages need to have a well-defined syntax and semantics in order for algorithms to have unambiguous and unchanging meaning. Someone could, in fact, write a formal syntax for a subset of English and give it unambiguous meaning. But this would be a huge, huge job.

### Its been done

Check out [BabelBuster](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/DeCSS/Baccash/). The idea here was to take C and convert it to and from a very small subset of very rigorous English such that one could write a program in C and then convert it to English. During the DeCSS DVD decryption arguments, the MPAA was trying to get programs that could decrypt their DVDs declared illegal. BabelBuster fought back with a very interesting idea. Create a way to convert English, which is protected under the freedom of speech into working code in C and thus make the point that C code is also just a language which should be protected as such. Therefor one should be able to publish code that cracks DeCSS. It's an interesting piece of work relevant to your question regardless of which side you're on.

The problem with BabelBuster is that you need to write your program in a very, very limited subset of English. But it is possible to do this.

### Conclusion

English, like all natural languages, allows us to describe a computation or algorithm but the language is verbose, offers many ways to say the same thing, is dependent on the context of the speaker, and not formally specified. If your goal is to describe computations, you should take English, chose a minimal workable subset in which you can say everything you need. Formally specify what each word in this subset will mean. Then create a few special notations to make it concise to say the things you say just like mathematics did. If you do this, you do this you'll end up with a typical programming language, or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to automatically [translate structured English into code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_programming), as long as a restricted subset of the English language is used.

As a proof-of-concept, I have developed an programming language called [EngScript](https://github.com/jarble/EngScript), which translates English sentences sentences into Python source code.

Arithmetic operations can be written in plain English:

```
#print{3 to the power of 2}
#print{3 raised to the power of 2}
#Both of these statements print "9".

print{3 plus (the sum of 1 and 2)}
#This prints "5".
```

Variables can be initialized in plain English, too:

```
let x be (x plus 1)
if (x is not equal to 7) :
    print x
```